# Getting NullPointerException when reading an S3 file with Spark

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-spark

I am trying to read an S3 file with Spark and getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.getFileStatus(NativeS3FileSystem.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.getFileStatus(Globber.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:248)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1642)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:304)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:203)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.getPartitions(MappedRDD.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:203)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:910)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:13)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:18)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:20)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:22)
    at <init>(<console>:24)
    at .<init>(<console>:28)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:852)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1125)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:674)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:705)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:669)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:828)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:873)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:785)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loop(SparkILoop.scala:641)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:968)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:916)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:916)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:916)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1011)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

It is just a textfile and I'm trying to read it using the following line of code (spark-shell):

```
sc.textFile("s3n://<bucket>/mypath/file.csv").count
```

The credentials (fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId and fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey) have been set properly using an ad hoc core-site.xml file (Hadoop is not installed on the machine).

What am I missing ?

Comment: it looks like the file (file.csv) is not accessible for some reason... Double check whether the file is there, or copy it somewhere and try to access the other location ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was an issue with the permissions. By default, permissions are given to the AWS user only. If you use IAM authentication with access keys, you must add permissions to "authenticated users" in S3.

Comment: Could you please provide more details on your solution?  I used the [spark-ec2 script](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html) to launch a Spark cluster.  I tried to use the `--copy-aws-credentials option`, but that didn't work so I used the `fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId` method you mention after the cluster was up.  Now I'm getting the same error, but am not sure if your solution applies in my case, and if so how I would go about adding these permissions.

Comment: Nevermind.  My problem is that I am supplying an S3 "folder" as input (to `jsonFile`), and Spark is trying to read the folder as a file.

Comment: @Nicola Ferraro Could you please tell what exactly was the permissions issue? I also use IAM authentication with access keys and getting the same error.